# Highligth selected item on list , when the customadapter also has focusable items?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a custom adapert which has buttons to perform some functions.
Now other thing is need is OnItemClickedlistener and the selected should be highlighted .
But listview onitemselected listner is not working , how can i do it.

Here's my getView of custom adapter.

```
public View getView(final int position,View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.businessbrieflist,null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.callButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.call);
    holder.favButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else   
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();   


                holder.toProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Profile","Clicked");
                Intent t = new Intent(context,BusinessProfileActivity.class);
                ///t.putExtra("index",position);
                t.putExtra("index",arrayListBusinessList.get(position).getBusinessid());            
                TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) context;
                parentActivity.startChildActivity("BusinessProfile", t);

            }
        });
    }

    convertView.setFocusable(true);
    convertView.setClickable(true);
    convertView.setId(position);    

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!favorite)
            {
                Utility.debugger("POSITION"+position);
                                    parent.getChildAt(index).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


                            parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
                            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

     //your code here

    }
```

for highlighting the selected item you can add in your xml file of listview as follows:

```
android:listSelector="Anydrawableimage/any colorcode(e.g #ffffff)"
```

Comment: Where to call onlistItemClick. Coz OnItemClickListener doesnot work

Comment: just write it outside onCreate() function of your activity

Comment: there must be wrong with your code beqcause both OnItemClickListener and onListItemClick() will work.

Comment: There is nothing in code in ListActivyt class only getListView().setAdapter(new BusinessListAdapter(getParent(), arrayListFavoriteVO,false,categoryIcon)); getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); } });

Comment: There is nothing in code in ListActivyt class only getListView().setAdapter(new BusinessListAdapter(getParent(), arrayListFavoriteVO,false,categoryIcon)); getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); } });